# Sublime text when building .rb file it fails and give me "bash: ruby: command not found"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, sublimetext

I have a file called "solutions.rb" and I'm trying to build it and see the output using sublime text.

the content of solutions.rb

```
puts "Hello world"
```

after pressing ctrl+B to build the file I got this error

```
bash: ruby: command not found
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 127]
[shell_cmd: ruby "/home/elta3lab/Desktop/solution.rb"]
[dir: /home/elta3lab/Desktop]
[path: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin]
```

knowing that I tried some solutions from answers I foudn on stackoverflow, but they never work, and I didn't understand every command I wrote because I'm not that good with linux.

[image]

Comment: Where is your ruby installed? From a bash prompt: `type -a ruby`

Comment: ruby is /home/elta3lab/.rbenv/shims/ruby

Comment: Have you tried something like [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/80580/246354)?

Comment: From the `path` error message, sublime cannot find that ruby. Try `PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH" sublime` to launch your editor. Or perhaps sublime has a configuration setting to specify the path to your ruby interpreter.

Comment: @glennjackman here's the output I got for  PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH" sublime .. sublime: command not found

Comment: The path you see at the bottom of the build output is the path as Sublime sees it, which doesn't include the path `ruby` is apparently installed in. Is there some command that you need to execute in a fresh terminal in order to set up the path to ruby or something?

Comment: @OdatNurd not sure but all I know is that sublime text can't read or detect ruby

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ruby is not installed on your system.

Open the terminal, them run the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL

git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL

rbenv install 2.5.1
rbenv global 2.5.1
ruby -v
```

Them try compiling it again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they are already installed but it's not found so maybe it's not in the default path. On a shell console try this (it's already suggested in a previous answer to your question):

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

Then issue a `which ruby`. See if it returns anything. Try also a `ruby -v` and see if it prints the ruby version.

If you have installed ruby using **rbenv** please double check if you installed it system wide or for a specific user. If you installed it as root let's say, when you're running sublime as a regular user, it won't find **ruby**. Either install it using **rbenv** for that specific user you're trying to run Sublime or install it system wide using a package manager so **ruby** will be available for all the users of that linux system.

Comment: after applying the two commands, "which ruby" returns nothing, I don't remember how I installed it, how can I check it it's installed using rbenv or not, and for specific user or system wide ?